# Limit to infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function and $f'(x)>x^2$  for every $x<0$, find
>   $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x).$$

I have so far observed that $f(x)$ is increasing in $(-\infty,0)$ therefore its range will be
($\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}f(x), f(0))$ but have no idea how to continue. Maybe I should somehow apply the Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already saw that $f$ is increasing, there are only two possibilities: 
$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=M$ for some $M\in\mathbb R$, or $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$. In the first case, however, the MVT gives us a sequence of $x_n\to-\infty$ with $f'(x_n)\to 0$ (why?), which conztradicts the bound on $f'$.

Answer (score 0):

I like your suggestion of the mean value theorem.

Since it's continuous and differentiable on every interval $(b..-1)$ we have that there exists a constant $c \in (b..-1)$ such that:

$$f(-1)-f(b) = (-1-b)f'(c) \ge -1 - b$$

The inequality comes from $f'(c) > c^2 \ge 1$.

So $-f(b) \ge -1 - b - f(-1)$, or $f(b) \le 1 + b + f(-1)$. If we let $b$ decrease without bound then $f(b)$ will also decrease without bound, because $f(-1)$ is constant.